# Split string and get first value only

Tags: c#, split

I wonder if it's possible to use split to devide a string with several parts that are separated with a comma, like this:

```
title, genre, director, actor
```

I just want the first part, the title of each string and not the rest?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```
string valueStr = "title, genre, director, actor";
var vals = valueStr.Split(',')[0];
```

vals will give you the title

Comment: That's kinda the obvious way... But really, you want to perform split on the whole string, just to get the first part? Imagine if the string was kinda long and if the operation was performed many times during the lifetime of the program, and maybe even in a loop for all records.

Comment: This is a good way when u want to use a string to split another one.
var vals=valueStr.Split("MySplit",0)[0];

Answer (score 26):

Actually, there is a better way to do it than split:

```
public string GetFirstFromSplit(string input, char delimiter)
{
    var i = input.IndexOf(delimiter);

    return i == -1 ? input : input.Substring(0, i);
}
```

And as extension methods:

```
public static string FirstFromSplit(this string source, char delimiter)
{
    var i = source.IndexOf(delimiter);

    return i == -1 ? source : source.Substring(0, i);
}

public static string FirstFromSplit(this string source, string delimiter)
{
    var i = source.IndexOf(delimiter);

    return i == -1 ? source : source.Substring(0, i);
}
```

Usage:

```
string result = "hi, hello, sup".FirstFromSplit(',');
Console.WriteLine(result); // "hi"
```

Comment: It will return a string or a char[] ?

Comment: @ivowiblo Good point. I fixed it. Edit: Actually removed it, because the extension methods are just so much nicer and better.

Comment: Didn't you wrote a simple way to use split in a comment?

Comment: Yes but it's really dumb to split the whole string just to get the first part, so I decided to remove it after a bit of thought. It was just `str.Split(',')[0]`.

Comment: But I like it and I tested it myself from the beginning, but without the []. Couldn't it be a alternative to your answer also? Why is it so dumb?

Comment: It works just fine, but it performs unnecessary actions. It's like you would calculate all prime numbers until 1000, just to get the 3rd prime number, except that example is a little worse.

Comment: I'm happy with it, and I was planning to accept your answer, but then I guess it should be a part of your answer as a alternative?

Comment: Consider comments as part of answer ;) But I really suggest going with the other approach, especially if you're doing this in a loop for many records or something like that.

Comment: I'm getting a red line below the .FirstFromSplit(','); Am I missing something?

Comment: +1 There is a little error in the second and third example (FirstFromSplit), it's only a typo and doesn't invalidate the rightness of this answer. Please correct/change input/source

Comment: Nice, but I think it's to much code compared with the split alternative!

Comment: It's one-time-writing code, and the usage is even cleaner: `myString.FirstFromSplit(',');`, but the more important thing is efficiency, in my opinion.

Comment: Yep. But he didn't ask for the most efficient nor the reusable way. Maybe he needs it only for this title matter and the split alternative will be way better than writing all that.

Comment: I don't understand how a two-lined extension method (which can be copy-pasted) can be referred to as "all that", really. Even if he only does that in one place in his code, he can have the method's logic implemented there (again - two lines). It's just a matter of doing things right instead of *just* making things work.

Comment: source.IndexOf(delimiter, StringComparison.Ordinal)

Answer (score 8):

You can do it:

```
var str = "Doctor Who,Fantasy,Steven Moffat,David Tennant";

var title = str.Split(',').First();
```

Also you can do it this way:

```
var index = str.IndexOf(",");
var title = index < 0 ? str : str.Substring(0, index);
```

Comment: The second one will fail if the string doesn't contain "," - though the split will return an array of size 1, containing the whole string.

Comment: And again, why `string.Empty`? The coder will expect the whole string to be returned, just as the whole string will appear in `splitResult[0]` (also a reason to change `FirstOrDefault()` to simply `[0]`, because the array will always have at least one element).

Comment: Why do you insist in using Linq? No need for `First` as well. People often think that Linq will make everything better, wrong. It will even be slower in this case, since the return type is an array so indexing is very fast, while using the Linq will probably use the enumerator of the array (why?!)

Comment: Yes, and assembler is faster than .NET. I think the code is more readable putting "first" instead of "[0]", and don't think the time that First() takes will be something considerable. In any case, you should optimize later. http://odetocode.com/aimages/200807/premature_6.jpg

Comment: Even though I found the picture disturbingly funny, this isn't "optimization". Other than that, most people will agree that `[0]` is MORE readable than `First`, but putting that aside as this is about personal preferences, `[0]` is about 17 times faster than `First` - let me say that again: **17 times faster.** And that is big enough of a difference to put aside readability and personal preferences. Especially as it is very logical that this will be called many many times.

Comment: Thinking of that at this point is premature optimization. If he won't be executing that code thousands of times per second, it doesn't matter.

Comment: You can call it premature thinking, but even then, it's just so normal to go with `[0]` that I don't see why not to. It's very pro-standard.

Comment: I really don't want to get into this silly argument, and I really don't have anything personal against you. I just thought it was strange so decided to point it out, then got carried away! In the end, both ways are readable and valid. :)

Comment: I never said it wasn't normal nor ok. I'm just telling you that using `First()` is not wrong and why I think is good.

Comment: I never said it was wrong :P just suggested why I think `[0]` is better.

Comment: "Why do you insist in using Linq? No need for First as well. People often think that Linq will make everything better, wrong."

Comment: It's not wrong using Linq, it is wrong thinking it will make everything better.

Answer (score 0):

These are the two options I managed to build, not having the luxury of working with `var` type, nor with additional variables on the line:

```
string f = "aS.".Substring(0, "aS.".IndexOf("S"));
Console.WriteLine(f);

string s = "aS.".Split("S".ToCharArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

This is what it gets:

[image]