# How can i filter a string by first few char

Tags: c#

I have a string variable called `price` which contains a range of price pattern as you can see in code. I want to filter it by its first part only.

```
string price = "9.99 -  12.99";
```

i already tried like bellow but this gives me wrong output something like ".99" however this is not my target output i am looking for.

```
string result = price.Substring(1, price.IndexOf("-") - 1);
```

The output i want like this- "9.99". Now can i filter this part from that string? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there no duplicate target for this one? What make it special ?

Comment: Here is a brunch of candidat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578254/to-get-specific-part-of-a-string-in-c-sharp , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868517/split-string-and-get-first-value-only ,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_ take a look at the remark/note part. It has some good exemple on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in C# are zero-based, so when you set the starting character as `1`, you're in fact starting from the second character. Just use `0` and you should be OK:

```
string result = price.Substring(0, price.IndexOf("-") - 1);
```

Note, by the way, that you could use the full `" - "` delimiter instead of playing around with index arithmetic:

```
string result = price.Substring(0, price.IndexOf(" - "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close but note that strings are `0` indexed:

```
string result = price.Substring(0, price.IndexOf("-") - 1);
```